stuck resolving metavariables in agda proof
I'm trying to prove a result for the following bizarre datatype in Agda. Here's the data type in question and its constructors (see SpLoc below):
-- supplemental data type for nats >= 2
data ℕ² : Set where
    two  : ℕ²
    succ : ℕ² -> ℕ²

toℕ² : ∀ n {_ : Positive n} -> ℕ²
toℕ²  0 {()}
toℕ²  1 {()}
toℕ² (suc (suc zero))       = two
toℕ² (suc (suc (suc n)))    = succ (toℕ² (suc (suc n))) 

to-nat : ℕ² -> ℕ
to-nat two = 2
to-nat (succ k) = 1 + to-nat k

-- spiral locations (sploc)
data SpLoc (A : Set) : ℕ² -> Set where
    cen : (k : ℕ²) -> (SpLoc A k)               -- center loc
    ss  : (k : ℕ²) -> (SpLoc A k) -> SpLoc A k  -- spiral successor
    rs  : (k : ℕ²) -> (SpLoc A k) -> SpLoc A k  -- radial successor

Certain properties are asserted involving iterated application of the spiral successor fn, so I also have an iterate function:
iterated : ∀ {A : Set}  -> (f : A -> A) -> ℕ -> A -> A
iterated f zero x = x
iterated f (suc n) x = f (iterated f n x)

This operator produces the 'distance' (number of hops) a given spiral location is from the center:
-- spiral center dist.
scd : ∀ {A : Set} -> ∀ (k : ℕ²) -> (SpLoc A k) -> ℕ
scd {A} k (cen k)   = 0
scd {A} k (ss k p)  = (scd k p) + 1
scd {A} k (rs k p)  = (to-nat k) * (scd k p) + 1  

The lemma/corollary I'm trying to prove about the above operator--followed by the steps I have made so far is below:
scd-03 : ∀ {A : Set} -> ∀ (k : ℕ²) -> ∀ (n : ℕ) -> scd k ( iterated (ss k) n (cen k) ) ≡ n 
scd-03 {A} k 0 = {- omitted, seems to go through -}
scd-03 {A} k (suc n) = 
    begin
        scd k (iterated (ss k) (suc n) (cen k))
    ≡⟨⟩ 
        scd k ( (ss k) (iterated (ss k) n (cen k)) )
    ≡⟨⟩ 
        (scd k (iterated (ss k) n (cen k))) + 1
    ≡⟨ +-comm (scd k (iterated (ss k) n (cen k))) 1 ⟩ 
        1 + scd k (iterated (ss k) n (cen k)) 
    ≡⟨⟩ 
        suc ( scd k (iterated (ss k) n (cen k)) ) 
    ≡⟨ cong (suc) (scd-03 {A} k n)  ⟩
        suc n 
    ∎ 

It seems that the steps match with the goal, although when running check once the above chain of rewrites is in place, I get the following error regarding unsolved metas (metavariables):
Failed to solve the following constraints:
  _A_38 (k = k) (n = (suc n)) = _A_38 (k = k) (n = n) : Set
    (blocked on _A_38)
_A_38 : Set
_A_47 : Set
_A_53 : Set

The +-comm specifically is in red (using VSCode extension here). Doing some reading, it seems like the issue might have to with implicit parameters, so I made the k explicit (was originally implicit) though it hasn't resolved the issue.
Any advice or tips on how to proceed or resolve this? Or dealing with metavariable errors in general?

What's the point of the (A : Set) parameter to SpLoc? It's not used anywhere and so cannot be reconstructed in the expression scd k ( iterated (ss k) n (cen k) ).

got it -- deleted the A : Set in the SpLoc type definition (was assuming initially locations would hold some piece of data of some type but it is indeed redundant here); the proofs now go through.

The scd in scd-03's type signature is highlighted in yellow, which means that it's missing implicit arguments. Writing scd {A} instead solves it.
